# How to convert an array into columns and another as values in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

## Overview

### Query

```sql
WITH 
  table_1 AS (...),
  table_2 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 1
  table_3 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 2
  table_4 AS (...)  -- Some Transformation on 3 and a Join
  
  SELECT
    user_id,
    feature_names, 
    feature_values 
  FROM table_4
  WHERE uuid = "xxx"
```

### Output

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| user_id |                 feature_names                 |             feature_values                 |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|    1    | ["feature_a", "feature_b", ... , "feature_n"] | ["value_a1", "value_b1", ... , "value_n1"] |
|    2    | ["feature_a", "feature_b", ... , "feature_n"] | ["value_a2", "value_b2", ... , "value_n2"] |
|   ...   |                    ...                        |                   ...                      |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

### Desired Output

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
| user_id | feature_a | feature_b |  ... | feature_n |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
|    1    | value_a1  | value_b1  |  ... | value_n1  |
|    2    | value_a2  | value_b2  |  ... | value_n2  |
|   ...   |    ...    |    ...    |  ... |    ...    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
```

### Constraints

1. I cannot do away with the CTEs as the transformations and joins are
   too complex to be handled in a Single Query.
2. The array of `feature_names` can change based on the `uuid`. However, it will be constant for a given `uuid`. The following are the properties of the `feature_names`:

   - `feature_names` can be of varying lengths. i.e. One `uuid` can have 10 values in the array but another can have 5.
   - The values of `feature_names` are not fixed. i.e. Even if two `uuids` have the same number of features, it's not necessary that the names would be the same. One can have `[ "a", "b", "c" ]` and another can have `[ "x", "y", "z" ]`

Given the above constraints, it's clear that we really cannot "hardcode" the `feature_names` by doing something like:

```sql
WITH 
  table_1 AS (...),
  table_2 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 1
  table_3 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 2
  table_4 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 3 and a Join
  
  table_5 AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(feature_values) as feature_values
  FROM table_4
  WHERE uuid = "xxx"
  )

  SELECT
    user_id
    feature_values[ORDINAL(1)] AS feature_a,
    feature_values[ORDINAL(2)] AS feature_b,
    ... - Extracting other Features by accessing array elements
    feature_values[ORDINAL(n)] AS feature_n,
  FROM table_5
```

## Approaches Tried

### Converting data to Long-Format and then to Wide-Format

#### Long-Format Query

```sql
WITH 
  table_1 AS (...),
  table_2 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 1
  table_3 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 2
  table_4 AS (...), -- Some Transformation on 3 and a Join
  
  subset_table AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    feature_names, 
    feature_values 
  FROM table_4
  WHERE uuid = "xxx"
  ),
  
  long_format AS (
  SELECT 
    *EXCEPT(feature_names, feature_values, pos1, pos2),
    feature_names,
    feature_values
  FROM final_data,
  UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(feature_names)) feature_names WITH OFFSET pos1,
  UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(feature_values)) feature_values WITH OFFSET pos2
  WHERE pos1 = pos2
  )

  SELECT * FROM long_format
```

#### Long-Format Output

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+
| user_id | feature_name | feature_value |
+---------+--------------+---------------+
|     1   | feature_a    | value_a1      |
|     1   | feature_b    | value_b1      |
|     1   |    ...       |   ...         |
|     1   | feature_n    | value_n1      |
|     2   | feature_a    | value_a2      |
|     2   |    ...       |    ...        |
+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

#### Issue when Converting Long to Wide Format

I tried declaring a constant and using `EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE` as illustrated in this [video](https://youtu.be/QWIGpplBUuQ), however, looks like if we are using CTEs, BigQuery only expects `SELECT` statements to be used. Therefore we cannot do:

```sql
DECLARE unique_features STRING;

... -- Code from the long-format query above

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
"""
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT("'",feature_name,"'")) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT feature_name FROM long_format)
""") INTO unique_features

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(
"""
SELECT 
  * 
FROM long_data
PIVOT(ANY_VALUE(feature_value) FOR feature_names IN(%s))
""", unique_features)
```

Any idea how can I achieve my desired outcome given the constraints?

**PS:** I will keep updating the **Approaches Tried** Section to keep you all posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **temp table** before pivoting:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE long_format AS
WITH
table_1 AS (SELECT 1),
table_2 AS (SELECT 2), -- Some Transformation on 1
table_3 AS (SELECT 3), -- Some Transformation on 2
table_4 AS (SELECT 4), -- Some Transformation on 3 and a Join

subset_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id,
         '["feature_a", "feature_b", "feature_n"]' feature_names,
         '["value_a1", "value_b1", "value_n1"]' feature_values
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,
         '["feature_a", "feature_b", "feature_n"]',
         '["value_a2", "value_b2", "value_n2"]'
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(feature_names, feature_values, pos1, pos2),
  FROM subset_table,
       UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(feature_names)) feature_name WITH OFFSET pos1,
       UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(feature_values)) feature_value WITH OFFSET pos2
 WHERE pos1 = pos2;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM long_format PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(feature_value) FOR feature_name IN ("%s"))
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT feature_name, '","') FROM long_format));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

consider below

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from long_format
pivot (any_value(feature_value) for feature_name in ("''' || string_agg(distinct feature_name, '","') || '"))'
from long_format 
);
```

Comment: Cannot use `execute immediate` with CTEs.

Comment: you should "save" it as a temp table first! like `create temp table long_format as ...`